# How to change Texture properties via python?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Changing texture data properties via python seem impossible because the properties are inherited from the texture Type

for example `texture.noise_scale` don't exists yet if `texture.type` is currently `"IMAGE"` because `texture.noise_scale` is a child property of some subclass types

so if you are starting from an image type
the following code won't be able to work

```
texture = bpy.data.textures["MyImgTexture"]
texture.type = "MARBLE" #changing type
texture.noise_scale = 5.5 #changing noise scale from this new type
```

What can we do to refresh the child properties? `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` won't help here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Recast the type**

For objects that can have their types changed can recast the types using `type_recast`

```
>>> tex.type_recast(
type_recast()
.. method:: type_recast()
Return a new instance, this is needed because types
such as textures can be changed at runtime.
:return: a new instance of this object with the type initialized again.
:rtype: subclass of :class:`bpy.types.bpy_struct`
```

try it out in console.

```
>>> tex = D.textures.new("Tex", 'STUCCI')
>>> tex.name
'Tex'

>>> tex.type
'STUCCI'

>>> tex.image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'StucciTexture' object has no attribute 'image'

>>> tex.type = 'IMAGE'
>>> foo = tex.type_recast()
>>> foo.image is None
True

>>> foo.name
'Tex'

>>> foo
bpy.data.textures['Tex']
```

Notice too the two instances keep there type

```
>>> str(tex)
'<bpy_struct, StucciTexture("Tex") at 0x7f89ff16b448>'

>>> str(foo)
'<bpy_struct, ImageTexture("Tex") at 0x7f89ff16b448>'
```

btw, if while checking this out in console the properties area is open on same screen, it is being done automatically for us.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit unintuitive but refetching the Texture after changing the type works for me :

```
import bpy

texture = bpy.data.textures["Texture"]
texture.type = "MARBLE" #changing type
texture = bpy.data.textures["Texture"] # This one has noise_scale attribute
texture.noise_scale = 2  #changing noise scale from this new type
```

Comment: speculate this is what is happening too if running py console code with properties editor open in same screen, when it sets `context.texture`  making the prop behave as tho it has an update method when changed.