# Converting Principled BSDF material to Diffuse BSDF and apply texture based on material name

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I have some objects with their corresponding materials defined as "Principled BSDF" I am trying to write a python script that transforms these materials to "Diffuse BSDF" and applies the corresponding texture image on them. For example currently I have the following:

[image]

Then this should be transformed to the following:

[image]

My texture files are already loaded so once I select that `Color` should be `Image Texture` I can then select the corresponding image file from the drop down list which matches my material name in this case it is `Tiles07` with a sufix `_2K_Color.jpg`

I've tried to loop through each object material and apply each change gradually:

```
import bpy

def map_correct_materials(obj):
    print("Obj name: {}".format(obj.name))
    for m in obj.material_slots:
        print("Material name: {}".format(m.name))
        
        mat = m.material
        if mat.use_nodes == True:
            
            for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                    print("Node name: {}".format(node.name))
                    print("Node type: {}".format(node.type))
                    print("Node input Base Color: {}".format(node.inputs['Base Color']))
                    node.type = 'BSDF_DIFFUSE'

objs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
    if o.type == 'MESH' and not "Light" in o.name]
    
for obj in objs:
    map_correct_materials(obj)
```

however I got a read only error when I tried to change the material type:

`AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "type" from "ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled" is read-only`

Searching around I couldn't find a reason for that though. Thus, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK if a type is read only can't re type it, as can with for instance textures. Eg can't `context.object.type = 'LATTICE'` to change an object into a lattice object. Hence will need to add a new BSDF_DIFFUSE   node , make links to it using links of old,  then remove old. Pretty sure there is a qa re exactly  this. (or vice versa)  @brockmann ?

Comment: Tangential note: the roughness on Principled and the roughness on Diffuse are not at all the same thing.

Comment: @batFINGER if apply these changes through the gui it works fine. Thus, why through the script complaints about being read only. Except if under the hood does what you suggest. @scurest well roughness isn't that much of a concern, the basic task is to covert it to `Diffuse BSDF` type and keep the texture.

Comment: Agree with @batFINGER, you'd have to replace the node (recently updated) -> [Update all materials, but keep their color and textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/update-all-materials-but-keep-their-color-and-textures/79839#79839)

Comment: That's the one.  @ttsesm confirm if that answers question  and will close as dupe. If you are referring to PROPERTIES material CHeck out the UI code is `layout.template_node_view(ntree, node, input)`  Not an enum of the node type property. Not aware of these being exposed to python   Have asked re the magic done by `template_constraint` using instance panels.   Re (aforementioned) textures and changing type https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215897/how-to-change-texture-properties-via-python

Comment: Thanks @brockmann, batFINGER let me have a look on the links and the code there and see how I can use them or not.

Comment: Glad I could help, just let us know whether that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while @brockmann's solution suggested above looks good it might be an overkill for what I want to do. Thus, taking into consideration @batFINGER's suggestion to create a new node and remove the previous one I came up with the following solution which seems to do what I want:

```
import bpy

def map_correct_materials(obj):
    print("Obj name: {}".format(obj.name))
    for m in obj.material_slots:
        print("Material name: {}".format(m.name))
        
        mat = m.material
        if mat.use_nodes == True:
            
            image_texture = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Image Texture')
            roughness = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Image Texture.001')
            normal_map = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Normal Map')
#            displacement = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Displacement')
            material_output = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')
            diffuse = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
            
            uv_map_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')
            uv_map_node.uv_map = "UVMap"
            normal_map.uv_map = "UVMap"


            # remap links and connect the diffuse shader to material
            mat.node_tree.links.new(uv_map_node.outputs['UV'], image_texture.inputs['Vector'])
            mat.node_tree.links.new(diffuse.inputs['Color'], image_texture.outputs['Color'])
            mat.node_tree.links.new(diffuse.inputs['Roughness'], roughness.outputs['Color'])
            mat.node_tree.links.new(diffuse.inputs['Normal'], normal_map.outputs['Normal'])
            mat.node_tree.links.new(material_output.inputs[0], diffuse.outputs[0])
            
            # Remove default
            mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')) #title of the existing node when materials.new

            # set activer material to your new material
            obj.active_material = mat
            

objs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
    if o.type == 'MESH' and "Floor" in o.name and not "Light" in o.name]
    
for obj in objs:
    map_correct_materials(obj)
```

Which mainly what it does is to remap the links from the existing nodes to the newly created one and then remove the one that is not needed anymore.