# Color alteration in writing and reading image textures using GPU module and Frament shader

Tags: python, scripting, shaders, gpu, glsl

I'm trying to understand how to use Fragment shaders in Blender for editing and saving some images. Collecting pieces of information here and there, I produced a simple code that read an image, draw the image as an offscreen frame buffer, and then save the image again.

What I realized, is that without introducing any alteration, the image values change. I am not sure, but maybe it depends on the function `gpu.texture.from_image`:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.texture.html?highlight=from_image#gpu.texture.from_image

By executing the code for some time, the image starts to get some contrast, while it is expected to remain unaltered.

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Here you can see my code. It requires an 'Untitled' image in the blender file, with some colours.

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import numpy as np

image_name = "Untitled"

image = bpy.data.images[image_name]
nx = image.size[0]
ny = image.size[1]


vertex_shader = '''
    in vec2 position;
    in vec2 uv;

    out vec2 uvInterp;

    void main()
    {
        uvInterp = uv;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
'''

fragment_shader = '''
    out vec4 FragColor;
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    uniform sampler2D image;
    
    void main(void){
        vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy)/resolution.xy;
        vec4 tex = texture2D(image, uv);
        FragColor = texture2D(image, uv);
    }
'''

# create Offscreen
offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(nx, ny)
offscreen.bind()
# Custom Shader
shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRI_FAN', {"position": ((-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1))})
shader.bind()
shader.uniform_float("resolution", (nx,ny))
shader.uniform_sampler("image", gpu.texture.from_image(image))
# Draw Shader
batch.draw(shader)
# Save Frame Buffer to Image
fb = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()
offscreen.unbind()
buffer = fb.read_color(0, 0, nx, ny, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')
buffer.dimensions = nx * ny * 4
imageData = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.float32)
image.pixels.foreach_set(imageData)
image.update()
```

Shaders are a completely new topic for me, and I hope that someone here can help find a solution. I would like to use the shaders as GPU computing method in Blender Python without the need to install external modules.

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: I have a feeling the problem may be _View Transform_ related - I may be wrong, but the first (before) image looks like _Standard_ Transform, where the second image (after) looks like it has a _Raw_ Transform. You may need to add some code to handle _Color Management_.

Comment: Thank @ChristopherBennett for the input, I actually found a very easy solution. I realized that the image's colour space by default is sRGB, while the function `gpu.texture.from_image` uses the linear mode. I, therefore, changed the colour space of the image to linear as well, and now the aspect of the image is preserved: `bpy.data.images["before.png"].colorspace_settings.name = 'Linear'`

Comment: Interesting... seems that when I use "Linear", it loses the interactivity. For instance, when I repeat the operation in a loop (using the frame_change handler), then it crashes if I try to paint the image. This does not happen with the "Raw" colour space. Also, the chromatic aberration seems fine with "Raw".

Comment: It may be because pointers to images and textures become funky when you change their settings. Maybe try [type_recast](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=type_recast#bpy.types.bpy_struct.type_recast)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Gorgious, where would you use that? In the line `shader.uniform_sampler("image", gpu.texture.from_image(image))`?

Comment: `image = image.type_recast()` before this line. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215897/how-to-change-texture-properties-via-python although after closer inspection I don't think that's the culprit :p